# Transform ColumnDataSource back into DataFrame in Bokeh

Tags: pandas, dataframe, bokeh

I want to transform a CDS object containing my data back into a DataFrame object since there's still much cleaning to do before I actually pass the values to my glyphs. How can I do that?

I tried

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_cds_object)
```

But it raised

`ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!") ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Answer (score 0):

CDS Objects (`bokeh.models.ColumnDataSource`, [docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.AjaxDataSource.to_df))  support a `.to_df()` call, so you can use:

```py
my_df = my_cds_object.to_df()
```